# actions::transform fails on std::vector<T>, where T is a POD struct

Tags: c++, range-v3

This works just fine:

```cpp
    std::vector<int> ints{10, 20, 30};
    auto floats = ints | ranges::to_vector
        | ranges::actions::transform([](auto n){ return 1 / float(n); });
```

Now, given the following struct:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    int* hello;
    int num;
    float yes;
};
```

The equivalent code:

```cpp
    std::vector<Foo> foo;
    auto bar = foo | ranges::to_vector
        | ranges::actions::transform([](auto f){ return f.hello; });
```

will not compile. Digging through the error message to find the actual error (with concepts enabled), you'd find that the `invocable_` concept is not satisfied, which usually means the transform function can't be applied to `Foo`.

Why doesn't this work? `Foo` is trivially copyable just like `int`, so it makes no sense that a generic lambda wouldn't be applicable here.

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/YWWYxn4bq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are using `ranges::actions::transform`. Range-v3 has two transform functions: one is an *action* that transforms the entire input range, producing a new range of the same type; the other produces a *view* object that transforms each element lazily upon iterating.

The action works on the int vector because the transformation returns values that can be assigned to integers, but in the second example, `int*` cannot be assigned to `Foo` values.

Note that this also means that your first example produces a `std::vector<int>` containing three zeroes. To obtain a `std::vector<float>` instead, use the transform view and place it before `to_vector`:

```
std::vector<float> floats = ints 
    | ranges::views::transform([](auto n){ return 1 / float(n); })
    | ranges::to_vector;
```

Comment: OH! Whoops... I really thought actions were able to transform the type of the input container, _eagerly_ producing a new container as a result. The fact that the resulting range _has_ to be of the same type really isn't clear to me from reading the documentation. Thanks!